# output sql statement is grouped

Tags: mysql

I have a little problem, have the following statement in mysql:

```
SELECT cmfilm.*, cmgenre.titel AS genretitel, cmvertoning.*, cmzaal.titel AS zaaltitel 
FROM cmfilm 
      LEFT JOIN cmvertoning ON cmvertoning.film_id=cmfilm.id 
      LEFT JOIN cmgenre ON cmfilm.genre_id=cmgenre.id 
      LEFT JOIN cmzaal ON cmvertoning.zaal_id=cmzaal.id 
WHERE cmvertoning.id IN(74,74,74,74) 
ORDER BY cmfilm.id ASC
```

because i'm asking the same id 4 times it only gives  me 1 result. But i would like to have the result to be returned 4 times, as i asked it to do. Anyone who knows how to solve this?

Comment: You could always just do 
`query union all query union all query union all query`

Comment: This is a bit weird, though. (Why) do you (really) want 4 identical results? (Which is what you'll get). If it's because you're expecting 4 different rows (based on a table linked to your primare table), your query will need to change.

Comment: are you sure you want cmvertoning.id instead of cmvertoning.film_id or cmvertoning.zaal_id in your WHERE clause??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would be better to achieve this on the application side - put returned rows in a map, then iterate over the ids you wanted and get appropriate rows from a map. Because there is another problem - the rows might not be in the order in which order you specified the ids (BTW. this row ordering problem can be solved also using [field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)).

The UNION solution would work too. But, honestly, I think that you have some design problem if you need to fetch the same rows multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You did not ask for 4 rows, you asked for any rows where `id` is 74, 74, 74 or 74 - of which there is only one.

The real question is, why do you want the same row 4 times?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can acomplish that without some sort of a loop, or by using the UNION ALL statement.